# How to use SUM aggregate function in queries with Lithium PHP framework

Tags: php, lithium

How to use SUM aggregate function in queries with Lithium PHP framework.

I wanted to fetch sum of a column value. How to do this in Lithium Frame work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer of question. Posting here now.

'fields' => 'SUM(quantity) AS total',

Where 'quantity' is column name.

Thanks,

Comment: You can also do `'fields' => ['SUM(quantity) AS total', ...]` to include other fields as well.